# Get jquery.ui.theme.css and jquery.ui.autocomplete.css from internet

Tags: c#, jquery, css

In BundleConfig.cs, I had this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.all.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

And then I switched to using the Google Hosted libraries::

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My problem is that some of the css’s aren't being used, in particular I’ve noticed `jquery.ui.theme.css` and `jquery.ui.autocomplete.css`. Without these, the display of autocomplete is messed up. So for the moment at least I am including just those, like so:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css", 
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

In _Layout.cshtml I have:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Looking at the jquery-ui source code, I do see theme.css and autocomplete.css. So I am not sure what is going wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the source of the page and look for the order the stylesheets are being loaded. Maybe one is overwriting the other.

Comment: Yea, I've tried changing the order of things and then more after you suggested it, but nothing. Now I've run across something (link after) that says you should write your code such that, if the CDN (Google hosted libraries in this case) fails, you then revert to local copies. In which case, why reference the CDN at all? I think I'm giving up on this, at least for now.   http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx